# How to create a heat\grid\colored map using a equation python?

Tags: python, mapping, heatmap, mesh, equation

I want to create a coloured map using an equation, like sound propagation. Basically I want to put the source in the middle of the map (or anywhere) and project how the intensity decrease in relation with the distance from the source.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# mesh
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 10)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# center point
p = [0,0]

# Distance
R = np.sqrt((((p[0]-X)**2)+((p[1]-Y)**2)))

# Equation
z = [np.round(10 * np.log10((((((R/(1000**(1/3)))**-1.45) * 516)/(20**(-3)))**2)),0) for R in range(1,101) ]

# Ploting
Z= np.array(z).reshape(len(y),len(x))

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

I have the following problems:

1. The source is not the the center
2. It seems the projection is still in one direction, should be to all directions
3. The distances are wrong, be cause is supposed are just 8 meters (-4 to 4) but in the buckle I had to put range (1, 101) and the intensity is calculated with 100 meters! I did it cause the reshape function needs the same size (10x10).

So far, this is my output:

[image]

And I want to do something similar to this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `R` in `z`; try

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# mesh
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# center point
p = [0, 0]

# Distance
R = np.sqrt((p[0] - X) ** 2 + (p[1] - Y) ** 2)

# Equation
z = np.round(
    10 * np.log10(((((R / (1000 ** (1 / 3))) ** -1.45) * 516) / (20 ** (-3))) ** 2),
    0,
)

# Ploting
Z = np.array(z).reshape(len(y), len(x))

plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image]